# What kind of sentinel unit should I expect to see for each star rating?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I know that level one and two have the small flying Sentinels, and level 3 has the dog-looking thing.

I was hoping someone had a smarter, more definitive list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out the expected appearance section in [this wiki](http://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Sentinel).

**While on Land:**

- At level 1, expect 1 to 2 drones.
- At level 2, expect 3 drones.
- At level 3, expect 1 to 3 drones and a quadrapedal Sentinel.
- At level 4, expect 2 drones and 1 walker.*
- At level 5, expect 4 drones, 2 quadrapedals, and 2 walkers.‡

*A level 1 wanted level will be placed on you if you flee into space.

‡Your wanted level will not go away unless you leave the planet.  A level 1 wanted level will be placed on you when you enter space.

---

**While in Space:**

- At level 1, expect 1 Sentinel Starship
- At level 2, expect 2 Sentinel Starships
- At level 3, expect 3 Sentinel Starships
- At level 4, expect 4 Sentinel Starships
- At level 5, expect 1 Sentinel Starship Carrier.  This will spawn 3-5 Sentinel Starships at once.  It will disappear once you lose your wanted level.